# C: how to implement dynamic function copying?

Tags: c, gcc, callback, entry-point

I have a static function which is meant for receiving C-style callbacks. Doing some experiments with multithreading approaches, want to try a way of receiving callback into functions at different addresses, but do not want to declare all of them in code, rather copying a function (with its entrypoint) to another address in memory, and registering that adrress with a callback. Also it is required to determine address of function entrypoint at the function body..

Any possiblity to reach this with C and particularly with gcc on Linux?

*Note: in my case, callback happens with an argument, which is unique for it's source - so I have no problems with distinguishing callback origins.. however, I feel the need of described approached for multithreaded+forked environment - even there, the callback will be recognized either by handle or process/fork/thread ID*

**Edit:** forking doesn't works: in the following code, realme() and testme() are sharing addresses; I think about `-finstrument-functions`, `backtrace()` and some other chances to implement memcpy+pointer way (see comments somewhere below)..

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>
// Required by for routine
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   // Declaration for exit()
using namespace std;
int globalVariable = 2;

void realme()
{
    cout << "Testme() is at: " << __builtin_return_address(1) << std::endl;
}
void testme()
{
    realme();
}
    main()
    {
       string sIdentifier;
       int    iStackVariable = 20;
       pid_t pID = fork();
       if (pID == 0)                // child
       {
          // Code only executed by child process
          sIdentifier = "Child Process: ";
          globalVariable++;
          iStackVariable++;
        }
    else if (pID < 0)            // failed to fork
        {
        cerr << "Failed to fork" << endl;
        exit(1);
        // Throw exception
        }
        else                                   // parent
        {
          // Code only executed by parent process
          sIdentifier = "Parent Process:";
        }
        // Code executed by both parent and child.
        cout << sIdentifier;
        cout << " Global variable: " << globalVariable;
        cout << " Stack variable: "  << iStackVariable << endl;
        testme();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this reliably, in C. There's no guarantee that the code residing inside a function is independent of its own position (think about local branches), once it's executing. There's no way to get the size of a function in C, so you wouldn't know how much to copy.

Comment: let's think I do `malloc` for `sizeof(known_size_of_function_body)`, copy the whole function body and call it like `int (*ptr)() x; x(100)` - the idea is taken from http://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/102703-passing-function-pointer-using-message-queues.html - this way I still cannot change any value within function copy - different compilers will change the body differently - but can I receive a pointer to function start in runtime?

Comment: to @unwind, look at sample code at http://citforum.ru/book/cook/selfmod.shtml - trying to adopt, will comment later

Answer (score 1):

This would require you to make self modifying code, apart from the fact that it is not that simple it also gives you a huge performance penalty. The only way to simulate the needed stuff without too much trouble is to make some sort of macro that will write a new function each time you need to pass a callback function pointer, but it has to be know at compile time. Maybe the macro can generate a function, based on certain parameters, to a .c file each time you referenced it.

P.S not talking about `#define` but rather an app that will be called at pre-compile time, search for a keyword and make an entry to a .c file

Comment: well.. preprocessor macros are ugly, but 10 similar functions in main code are even more ugly.. would think on it.